# Exclude image urls from redirection using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My old blog was at www.example.com/myblog
I changed my server and I want to use www.example.com/blog

To do this I used htaccess code
Redirect 301 /myblog http://www.example.com/blog

This helped in redirecting the blog home page and individual blog posts.

The images were put in a folder named myblog in the new server.
So the image url is www.example.com/myblog/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/something.jpg

But the htaccess I wrote above redirects this to www.example.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/something.jpg which returns 404.

Can anyone help me to write htaccess code for redirecting blog post urls only excluding the blog image urls?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mod_alias and the `Redirect` directive, try mod_rewrite and add some conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?myblog/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301]

# redriect the index
RewriteRule ^/?myblog/?$ http://www.example.com/blog/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Jon, Will this exclude images from redirection. That's my requirement

Comment: @NikhilRajR Yes, because the first condition is pretty much "if the request being made points to a file that **doesn't** exist", so if you request a /myblog/wp-content/uploads/ file, that'll be false and no redirect will happen.

Comment: Jon, Thanks. It worked. I will study htaccess. One more thing I need to know how can I make urls case insensitive using htaccess. When I search the results are like enable "CheckSpelling On", but I cant find this on the Cpanel..!

Comment: Just now I noticed there are two redirects happening for blog posts. One is from /myblog/post to /blog/post then to /post I think the reason for this is because I have the same WP installation for blog and website

Comment: There is an issue with the code you gave because when I accesss the old blog home page www.example.com/myblog there is no redirection happening. Pls help me with this..

Comment: @NikhilRajR just need to add a specific rule for the index, see the edit